# Does getting angry and shouting break wudu?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, wudu

Does getting angry with somone, keeping silent but then walking away and shouting "SABIR!" loud and hitting the wall nullify wudu? I know its not a good thing to get angry but I want to know If my prayer wouldn't be accepted and would I need to perform wudu again?

The image attached says "insanity" other places I read as "madness"

So is getting angry and shouting classed as any of these things?
[image]